# Can't override Devise::RegistrationsController in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, path, devise, registration

I'm trying to set a default behaviour after User sign in and sign up.

I've tried creating a *registration_controller.rb* with the following code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected


  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    "/projects"
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    raise
    "/projects"
  end

end
```

which doesn't even get me to the *raise*

As a workaround I've managed to make it work creating a method in *application_controller.rb* as follows:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    "/projects"
  end
```

but I would like to know why I wasn't overriding the default RegistrationsController class.

Comment: Does it work if you add `super` to the top of the RegistrationController, right under `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Devise documentation, you can customize its configuration by running `rails generate devise:controllers [scope]`, replacing scope by `users` for example.

Then it generates files like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  # GET /resource/sign_in
  # def new
  #   super
  # end
  ...
end
```

You can uncomment the methods you need and write your code after `super`.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually created the controller manually instead of by running the console command. I also had not added the custom route for the overriden controller.